# Bad Message 400 || reason: Illegal character SPACE=' '

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, http-headers

I keep getting this error when I send a request using Resttemplate in springboot. Anyone out there please advise. Bad Message 400 || reason: Illegal character SPACE=' '. See the code below.

RequesT

```
headers.set("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
headers.setBasicAuth("XXXX", "YYYY");
headers.set("X-Original Signer", "signer");
headers.set("X-Signature","signature");
HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(request, headers);

        try{
            String fetch=restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);            
            return new ResponseEntity<>(fetch, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

Resttemplate Config

```
 @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception{
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;

        SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(trustStore.getURL(), trustStorePassword.toCharArray(), acceptingTrustStrategy)
        .loadKeyMaterial(keystore.getURL(), keystorePassword.toCharArray(), keystorePassword.toCharArray()).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new LocalHostnameVerifier());
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    
        return new RestTemplate(factory);
    }

        private class LocalHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {

            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return "127.0.0.1".equals(hostname);
            }
            
        }
```

Expecting to Receive a Response from the API but it doesn't seem like i can get through to the API. please assist

Answer (score -1):

```
headers.set("X-Original Signer", "signer");
```

The space in the request header was the problem.